# Yii2 display serialized data in gridview

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have some data stored in serialized format.

I can pull the data and show it in view like this for the logged in user:

```
$user_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
$kids=unserialize($model->kids);
$children =\app\models\UserChildren::find()->where(['user_id' =>$user_id])->andwhere(['id'=>$kids])->all();
?>                              
<?php  foreach ($children as $child): ?>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
<tr>
<th><?php echo Yii::t('app', 'Kids Name')?> : </th>
<td><?php echo $child->child_name?>  </td>
<th><?php echo Yii::t('app', 'Kids Birth Date')?> : </th>
<td><?php echo $child->child_birth_date?>  </td>
<th><?php echo Yii::t('app', 'Kids Gender')?> : </th><td><?php echo $child->child_gender?>  </td>
</tr>
</table> 
<?php  endforeach; ?>
```

The kids data is stored in order table like this, which is linked to the table userchildren.

```
s:0:"";
a:4:{i:0;s:2:"10";i:1;s:2:"11";i:2;s:2:"25";i:3;s:2:"26";}  
a:2:{i:0;s:2:"10";i:1;s:2:"11";}
```

I have tried to display the same in gridview, but couldn't make out how I can achieve this:

like for example if I am using

```
[
  'label'=> 'Child',
  'value' => function($data){                         
          return $data->order->kids;
    }
         ],
```

I am getting the same data as I have shown.
I also tried foreach, but I am getting invalid argument foreach.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure If I have done correctly, but it appears to have the correct data.

The code I am using is like below:

```
[
'label'=> 'Child',
'value' => function($data){                
$kids=((unserialize($data->order->kids)));    
$children1=ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\UserChildren::find()->where(['id'=>$kids])->all(),'id','child_name');
return implode(', ',$children1);

     }
  ],
```